# How to get error message with MSTest TestContext?

Tags: c#, mstest

I'm trying to get the error message of a failed test case from mstest.

I found something online that uses TestContext and below is the code snippet I have.

```
public static string GetErrorMessageFromTestContext(TestContext testContext) {

        BindingFlags privateGetterFlags = BindingFlags.GetField |
                                            BindingFlags.GetProperty |
                                            BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                            BindingFlags.Instance |
                                           BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy;

        var m_message = string.Empty;
        Type t = testContext.GetType();

        if (testContext.CurrentTestOutcome == UnitTestOutcome.Failed)
        {
            var field = t.GetField("m_currentResult", privateGetterFlags);
            object m_currentResult = field.GetValue(testContext);

            field = m_currentResult.GetType().GetField("m_errorInfo", 
            privateGetterFlags);
            var m_errorInfo = field.GetValue(m_currentResult);

            field = m_errorInfo.GetType().GetField("m_message", 
            privateGetterFlags);
            m_message = field.GetValue(m_errorInfo) as string;
        }

        return m_message;
    }
```

This thing should return an error message from the failed case.  However, when executing the line:

var field = t.GetField("m_currentResult", privateGetterFlags);

field is being assigned with null.  Not sure what's the reason so I'm opened to other solutions as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution doesn't work, because this is MSTest v1 example, and most likely you are using MSTest v2. You won't find message in a `TestContext` in v2 because it doesn't exist there. You need to check `TestResult` class to get this message.

One way to get `TestResult` class is to override `TestMethodAttribute` and use it as in example below:

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest
    {
        [MyTestMethod]
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(false);
        }
    }

    public class MyTestMethodAttribute : TestMethodAttribute
    {
        public override TestResult[] Execute(ITestMethod testMethod)
        {
            TestResult[] results = base.Execute(testMethod);

            foreach (TestResult result in results)
            {
                if (result.Outcome == UnitTestOutcome.Failed)
                {
                    string message = result.TestFailureException.Message;
                }
            }

            return results;
        }
    }
}
```